# Is -fPIC implied on modern platforms

Tags: linux, gcc

I want to check whether a shared library was compiled with the `-fPIC` flag. What are the possible ways (on Linux, `x86_64`) to check this?

Is `-fPIC` implied (thus making the check redundant?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GCC wouldn't allow you to link shared library without `-fPIC` so you don't need to check anything:

```
$ gcc tmp.c -shared
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqQVR9Y.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `compare' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccqQVR9Y.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ gcc tmp.c -shared -fPIC
```

**EDIT**

Technically speaking you *can* compile shared library without `-fPIC` if none of it's functions calls other functions or accesses global variables. But in that case generated code would be the same as with `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 1):

Some architectures (not necessarily "modern" ones) just don't have absolute addressing modes, all code is position independent there.

Comment: I was specific as @yugr mentioned because it is the particular environment I am dealing with. But this info is useful as well.